# I want to delay a link using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, delay

I have a navigation menu on top of the page that redirects within a page. However, some of the divs are initially hidden and take 1 second to appear so the anchor tag doesn't move the browser window down far enough. I want to delay the link for a second to wait for the div to be visible before the window scrolls down.

The divs are opened using

```
$.slideToggle(1000)
```

and the nav menu uses a simple

```
<a href='#divid'>link to divid</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the set timeout function, and give it a delay before firing the next event.

```
$("#divid").bind("click", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#divid").slideToggle(1000);
    },1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ - according to docs, there you have a callback which allows you to do something when animation is done.

So, you can do something like this:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //this will prevent immediate scrolling
    $(this.href).slideToggle(1000, function(){ 
                                    document.location.hash = $(this).attr("id")//now hash will be changed and window should be scrolled to according div.
                                  });
});
```

Suppose this will work.